# What is the difference between i<=array.length and array.length>i

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans

We've started using netbeans in our Java programming class, after using notepad++ for a while. While iterating through an array list. I used the following code:

```
for (int i=0; i<=randomarrayhere.length; i++)
```

Netbeans suggested to flip the position of i and array.length

```
for (int i=0; randomarrayhere.length>i; i++)
```

What do we gain by this?

Thanks!

Comment: You gain nothing as such by doing that. I'm rather surprised that Netbeans suggested that edit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first would throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when `i` reaches `randomarrayhere.length`.

Aside from that (if you use `i<randomarrayhere.length`), there is no difference.

Answer (score 4):

you can either use `randomarrayhere.length>i` or `i<randomarrayhere.length`, but don't use `randomarrayhere.length>=i` or `i<=randomarrayhere.length` because if you call `randomarrayhere[i]` anywhere in your forloop you will get an Exception since array indices are zero-based.

Answer (score 1):

An array with 1 item has a length of 1, but the objects index in the array is 0. This throws an index out of bounds error. You can also do `x=array.length - 1` and use `=` in your comparison